# My remote server cannot recognize the variable using sftp in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, sftp

### my script

```
#!/bin/ksh 
ysdt=`date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%m%d'` 
expect << 'EOS'
spawn  sftp id@192.168.61.240:/data01/msc/huawei
expect "Password:"
send "password\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "mkdir $ysdt\n" 
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /data01/msc/huawei/$ysdt\n" 
expect "sftp>"
send "put /home/med/cdr/bak/hw/mss/prm/$ysdt/b*"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
EOS
```

-----error show-----------

```
can't read "ysdt": no such variable
    while executing
"send "mkdir $ysdt\n" "
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell isn't expanding the variable `ysdt`.

If any part of the word passed as delimiter for a here-document is quoted, no expansion occurs.
remove the quoting to have expansion occur.

i.e.

```
expect << EOS
```

Comment: if I remove the line " expect << EOS", then following error shows:./ftp_hw.sh[4]: spawn: not found [No such file or directory]
couldn't read file "Password:": no such file or directory
./ftp_hw.sh[6]: send: not found [No such file or directory]
couldn't read file "sftp>": no such file or directory
./ftp_hw.sh[12]: send: not found [No such file or directory]
couldn't read file "sftp>": no such file or directory
./ftp_hw.sh: line 14: send: not found

Comment: @arif7498: Don't remove the line, change `'EOS'` to `EOS`.